# Partial search in Lucene

Tags: lucene.net

I am using Lucene_29 for the search functionality.My code for the partial search in the lucene is

```
  var terms = input.Trim().Replace("-", " ").Split(' ')
            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(x => x.Trim() + "*");
        input = string.Join(" ", terms);
```

Here i am appending star to the input data for the partial search.When i pass the input as "swetha" or "swe". i am getting search data perfectly.But when i go for "wet". I am not getting the fields which contains "swetha". Can any one please help me to find the solution.
and i am parsing my input like this

```
query = parser.Parse(input.Trim());
```

Comment: To start with, you are not prepending your strings with *, only appending. Secondly, doing a wildcard search "from both ends" are very suboptimal, and maybe not even supported in Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use wildcards on both ends, you will need to set the AllowLeadingWildcard option on the `QueryParser` to true.

As jishi stated, this is very suboptimal and potentialy very slow, as it will scan your entire term dictionary.

[link to setAllowLeadingWildcard documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_4/api/core/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html#setAllowLeadingWildcard%28boolean%29)